# .NET Framework 4.7.2 Standalone Setup performs a reboot even with commandline /norestart

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework, windows-installer, setup

On one of my Windows 7 systems, I have experienced the following behaviour when trying to install the .NET 4.7.2. redistributable. I use a script to call the setup silently /q, and to prevent reboots, I also pass the commandlineargument /norestart.

My commandline:

> NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe /q /norestart

In Windows eventlog, I get exactly 7 entries, that also state that the reboot should be delayed:

> Product: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 - Update 'KB4087364' installed successfully.
>
> Windows Installer installed an update. Product Name: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2. Product Version: 4.7.03062. Product Language: 0. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Update Name: KB4087364. Installation success or error status: 0.
>
> Product: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 -- Installation completed successfully.
>
> Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2. Product Version: 4.7.03062. Product Language: 0. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 0.
>
> Windows Installer requires a system restart. Product Name: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2. Product Version: 4.7.03062. Product Language: 0. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Type of System Restart: 2. Reason for Restart: 1.
>
> Product: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2. Restart required. The installation or update for the product required a restart for all changes to take effect.  **The restart was deferred to a later time.**
>
> Ending a Windows Installer transaction: E:\ae30b4c0e0b76eaaeb399c2a734a94\netfx_Full_x64.msi. Client Process Id: 6224.

What actually happens is that the system performs a reboot, and I do not really know why. I only know that this only happens if previously, an older version of .NET Framework 4.6.2 was previously isntalled on the system.

Is there any way to **really** suppress the reboot?